# Криптография PHP

Tags: php, криптография

Хочу написать модуль экстренного обновления, идея заключается в том, чтобы 'evalить' пришедший код от меня. Только тут одно но, проблема в безопасности. Получается кто-то левый может отправить такой запрос. Наслышан об односторонних алгоритмах криптографии, типа AES256. Как мне шифровать нужный код и выполнять в PHP?

Comment: "Наслышан об односторонних алгоритмах криптографии, типа AES256." Плохо наслышаны. AES - алгоритм симметричного шифрования и все что им пошифровано можно расшифровать если есть ключ. Вам стоит посмотреть в сторону ЭЦП.

Comment: Так и должно быть. Я отправляю зашифрованный код, на клиентской стороне он расшифровывается по ключу, в случае успеха выполняется.

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос? Как шифровать - как хотите. RC4/AES/Blowfish/черт-знает-что.

Comment: Вопрос в реализации.

Comment: Реализации чего? mcrypt вас чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: @FilippMustang Вам правильно сказали, смотреть в сторону ЭЦП, т.е. несимметричного шифрования. Дело в том, что симметричные алгоритмы позволяют злоумышленнику, узнав ваш ключ расшифровки (а он будет в исходниках функции выполняющей eval) , зашифровать свой произвольный код таким ключем и отдать его на выполнение и он будет расшифрован и выполнен. А несимметричные алгоритмы позволят выполняющей стороне всегда знать, что код получен от вас, т.к. он зашифрован вашим закрытым ключем, не известным никому кроме вас